# Montecarlo method and JFrame (math and java problem)

Tags: java, swing, math, jframe, pi

I made a little program to approximate Pi and I would like to represent it. I started but I thought it would look better if the points outside the circle were red and the ones inside were green. I can't do it and I don't understand why the problem is there. I don't know if it is in pure math or in dev.

```
for(int i = 0; i<1000; i++) {
            double x = Math.random() * (500-250) + 250;
            double y = Math.random() * 250;
            double applyformula = (x - 250)*(x - 250) + (y - 250) * (y - 250);
            
            if(applyformula == y || (y*y) - 500 * y < applyformula ) {
                g.fillOval((int) x,(int) y, 5, 5);
                g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            } else { 
                g.fillOval((int) x,(int) y, 5, 5);
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                
            }
                
        
    }
```

If someone could help me, that will be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done in a simpler way.

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    double x = Math.random();
    double y = Math.random();
    double applyformula = (x * x) + (y * y);

    if (applyformula <= 1) {
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    } else {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
    }
    // Set the actual coordinates in a 250 pixels wide square.
    x *= 250;
    y *= 250;
    g.fillOval((int) x, (int) y, 5, 5);
}
```